# How to add node to parent node (currently selected node) in gojs?

Tags: javascript, gojs

I have written as

```
function attachlink() {
var url = "https://www.google.co.in";
var diagram = myContextMenu.diagram;
var node = new go.Node(go.Panel.Auto);
var shape = new go.Shape();
shape.figure = "RoundedRectangle";
shape.fill = "lightblue";
node.add(shape);
var textblock = new go.TextBlock();
textblock.text = "Hello!";
textblock.margin = 5;
textblock.cursor = "pointer";
textblock.click = function (e, obj) { window.open(url) };
node.add(textblock);
//diagram.add(node);
//var diagram = myContextMenu.diagram;
var it = diagram.selection.iterator;
while (it.next()) {
    var part = it.value;
    if (part instanceof go.Node) {
       part.addNodeData(node);
    }
}
diagram.commitTransaction("color nodes");
}
```

I am having trouble with in this part of code

```
 while (it.next()) {
    var part = it.value;
    if (part instanceof go.Node) {
       part.addNodeData(node);
    }
}
```

I think this line of code is not appending the node to the currently selected node

```
 part.addNodeData(node);
```

Answer (score 0):

`addNodeData` is a function of `Model` in GoJS. Adding a `GraphObject` (in this case the `go.Node` that you programmatically built) to a parent Node's visual tree would involve calling `add` on the parent Node.

`parentNode.add(childNode)`

This is the same function that you used when adding the `go.Shape` and `go.TextBlock` to the Node that you programmatically built.

One thing to worry about with this approach though is that you're adding a reference to the **same** `go.Node` to each `GraphObject` in `myDiagram.selection`. What you probably want to do is build the `go.Node` that you want to add to each element selected *in* the while loop such that the constructor is invoked each time and you're adding **distinct** `go.Node`s to each selected element rather than the same one.